# Query to monitor the double bookings in the database

Tags: sql

I need a query for the following requirement

> table name: hms_reservation_mst
>
> coloum name : reservation_no  , reserved_by

I want to know the reservation_no's for which a particular reservation_no has two different user_id's. Which means one particular reservation_no should not consists of two reserved_by.

Simple this is to monitor double bookings in the table.please help and write a query to identify such reservation_no's which has two user'id in the table.

Comment: Juergem, what happen's in our database is, the reservation_no is a primary key though if any two users is submitting the input at the same timestamp, then same reservation_no is coming for both the user's even though the reservation_no is a primary key, how does it happen? I am a fresher in database admin, so please guide me how to get rid of this problem . My client is killing me reg this.. Need suggestion's in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1):

Use a `having` clause to determine `reservation_no`s with more than 1 reservation.

```
select reservation_no 
from hms_reservation_mst 
group by reservation_no 
having count(distinct reserved_by) > 1
```

Comment: Juergem, what happen's in our database is, the reservation_no is a primary key though if any two users is submitting the input at the same timestamp, then same reservation_no is coming for both the user's even though the reservation_no is a primary key, how does it happen? I am a fresher in database admin, so please guide me how to get rid of this problem . My client is killing me reg this.. Need suggestion's in resolving this issue

Comment: Please ask another question regarding this and explain your situation in detail along with the table structure.